# Get Exact latitude,longitude against an address

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using goole geocoding api to fetch `latitude` and `longitude` of a particular address, for some cases it gives me closest to my desired location while some time the position returned by google is many meters away from my given address.My main concern here to ask is, is google the best geocoding provider of there are any third party solutions provide accurate `latitude, longitude`?

My google API format is something like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[My address, street 123, house 123]&key=[GOOGLE_API_KEY]
```

Please help out, Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on whether address you are looking for exists in Google database. If address exists you will get an exact ROOFTOP result, otherwise you will probably get a RANGE_INTERPOLATED result or something similar that is just attempt to find out the position of the address. Check a type of result to figure out if it is exact or interpolated.

Comment: you are right possible "location_type" are

ROOFTOP
RANGE_INTERPOLATED
GEOMETRIC_CENTER
APPROXIMATE

Best accurate is ROOFTOP